# how to solve this graph theory question?

Tags: graph-theory, computer-science

if G=(A,B,E) is a graph without directions.
and (i mean unite value) |A U B| =50
what is the max value of |E| ?

im very new at the topic and if there is anywebsite that also can explain more.. it will be very helpfull... thanks

WHAT I DID:
(probally its worng...)
if |A U B| =50 then max value of |A|=|B|=25 for each
what means the |E|=625
hopefully it correct?

Comment: Are you trying to ask what is the maximum number of edges in a bipartite graph with 50 vertices? Then yes, it's 625.

Comment: Yes !!!! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you mean that $G$ is an undirected bipartite graph with partite sets of vertices $A$ and $B$ and edge set $E$, with $|A \cup B| = 50$. So, you are asking for the maximum number of edges in a bipartite graph with 50 vertices.

The number of edges in a complete bipartite graph whose partite sets have size $m$ and $n$ respectively is $mn$. (Every edge contains exactly one vertex in the partite set of size $m$; for each of these $m$ vertices, there are edges to each of the $n$ vertices on the other side.)

And, given any bipartite graph $G$, obviously the complete bipartite graph on the same partite sets has at least as many edges as $G$. So your question boils down to finding $n$ between 0 and 50 so that $n(50-n)$ is maximized.

One way to do this is calculus: to find the maximum of $50n - n^2$,
solve for its derivative to be 0:
$$50 - 2n = 0$$
has the solution $n = 25$. This critical point is indeed a maximum (take the second derivative if you want to check).

Then the number of edges is $25 \cdot 25 = 625$.